# Parsing JSON React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have  JSON getting returned as:

```
[
   { 
      "node" : "GMC",
      "node1" : "2500",
      "node2" : [ { 
            
            "node2" : "GMC 2500",
            "location" : "Lot",
         }]
   }
]
```

I want to parse this out and put in a UL, however, I get an error such as
[ objects are not valid as reach child (found: object with keys { node, node1 })

I'm trying to read it such as

```
{types.map(data => {
  <li> {data.node} // this displays GMC
    <ul> { data.node1 } </ul> //get the error.
     <ul> { data.node1.node1 } </ul> //also gives same error) 
 }
```

I need to show it as:

```
GMC
   2500
   Lot
```

is there another way to parse  out this JSON file?

Comment: I can see why data.node1.node1 is undefined since it is indeed undefined, but in the console i just prinited data.node1 and it displayed 2500 so i think you might be a bit turned around on that part.  you sure you didnt mean data.node2.node2?

Comment: According to your JSON Object, data.node1.node1 does not exist. Hence, it will show undefined. To identify the issue with data.node1, you need to share more info such as the error message.

Comment: @Ukarsh, the error is in the OP.  [ objects are not valid as reach child (found: object with keys { node, node1 })

Comment: Either the code or the data is not as you think it is or as shared in your question. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code (ul should contains li, not the opposite. Also data.node1.node1 doesn't exist). But you can try something like:
See on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c7h29b8/2/)

```
render() {
    const types = [
       { 
          "node" : "GMC",
          "node1" : "2500",
          "node2" : [
            { "node2" : "GMC 2500", "location" : "Lot" }
          ]
       }
    ]

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            types.flatMap(data => ([
                <li>{data.node}</li>,
                <li>{data.node1}</li>,
                data.node2.map(node2 => ([
                    <li>{node2.node2}</li>,
                    <li>{node2.location}</li>,
                ]))
            ]))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `=>()` to return .
2. `data.node1.node1` is `undefined` because `node1` is not an object it's a string so it does not have propreties
3. `li` should be an `ul` child not the inverse.
4. return an array of `li`:

```
<ul>
types.map(data =>
([
  <li>{data.node}</li>,
  <li>{data.node1}</li>,
])
</ul>
```

5.(bonnus) `types` is not a valid JSON but it does not matter here you can check if your JSON is valid [here](https://jsonlint.com)